# Cannot navigate directory in my terminal on mac OS X. I got “No such file or directory”

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, bash, terminal

I want to navigate directory in terminal. But I always got error message like this

> “-bash: cd/Applications/Xcode-beta: No such file or directory”

My mac OS X is El Capitan. I am using the following command on my terminal.

```
Macs-Mac-mini:~ macmini1$ cd/Applications/Xcode-beta 2.app
-bash: cd/Applications/Xcode-beta: No such file or directory
Macs-Mac-mini:~ macmini1$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want `cd "/Applications/Xcode-beta 2.app"` instead of `cd/Applications/Xcode-beta 2.app`. Note the space after cd. What you were trying to do was to execute the file in `cd/Applications/` called `Xcode-beta` with `2.app` as an argument, but obviously - it does not exist.

Also, note the quotation of `Xcode-beta 2.app`. Cd accepts only one argument and since there's a space in the name of this directory ( on side note - this doesn't look like a directory name, but who knows ) it will be interpreted as a separate argument to cd.

Comment: Minor extension to your answer: Instead of quoting the path with `"` you could also escape the space with a backslash. Pro tip: if you use tab completion the space is escaped automatically ;)

Comment: @RamboRamon While this is correct and probably easier to type, one might argue about the readability. Life would be much more simple if people'd just avoid spaces in filenames.

Comment: I did not intend to imply that escaping is better than quoting. Since it is mostly a matter of taste I just wanted to add this option to your perfectly fine answer. I definitely agree that files/directories with spaces in it are directly from hell.